# PHPMAILER Not Working but Default mail function automatically running

Tags: php, phpmailer, registration, email-verification

```
/*send email Using at Index.php page*/
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
            $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at demo site.</p>
            <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
            <p>Regards Site Admin</p>";
            //include 'classes/phpmailer/mail.php';         
            //function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)

            $mail = new Mail();
            //$mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);

            //$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            //$mail->setFrom('noreply@domain.com', 'noreply'); 
            //$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
            $mail->subject($subject);
            //$mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();

/*PHP Mailer Code used in mail.php*/ 
    <?php   
    include('class.phpmailer.php');
    class Mail extends PhpMailer

    //function Send_Mail($subject,$body)
    {
        // Set default variables for all new objects
        public $From     = 'rssbmonthlyreport@gmail.com';
        public $FromName = SITETITLE;
        public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        public $Mailer   = 'isSMTP';
        public $SMTPAuth = true;
        public $Username = 'abc@gmail.com';
        public $Password = 'password';
        public $SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        public $Port = 587;
        public $Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
        public $CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
        public $Encoding    = '8bit';
        public $ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
        //public $From        = 'rssbmonthlyreport@gmail.com';
        //public $FromName    = 'GMail Test';    
        public $WordWrap = 75;

        public function subject($subject)
        {
           return $this->Subject = $subject;
        }

        public function body($body)
        {
           return $this->Body = $body;
        }

        public function send()
        {
            $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
            $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
            return parent::send();
        }
    }
```

I am Using these code above at Index page and this in email.php and email.php was included in config.But it is not working in place of this default mail() function running.....I tried every thing even the latest code of phpmailer its crashing..Anyone has idea so please help

Comment: what error shown when you send?

Comment: no Error it just dont work and just send email using email() php function

Comment: See Webapp Url monthlyreport.ultimatefreehost.in

Comment: Try enabling verbose debugging? `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` Probably find that the connection is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$Mailer   = 'isSMTP';
```

It should be:

```
$Mailer   = 'SMTP';
```

A better approach would be to call `$this->isSMTP()` from an overridden constructor.

I'd also recommend using the built-in `html2text` method if you're going to forcibly set `AltBody` like that.

If you're going to override things, *read the code*.

Here's an improved version:

```
class Mail extends PhpMailer

    //function Send_Mail($subject,$body)
    {
        // Set default variables for all new objects
        public $From     = 'rssbmonthlyreport@gmail.com';
        public $FromName = SITETITLE;
        public $Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        public $SMTPAuth = true;
        public $Username = 'abc@gmail.com';
        public $Password = 'password';
        public $SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        public $Port = 587;
        public $Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
        public $CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
        public $Encoding    = '8bit';
        //public $From        = 'rssbmonthlyreport@gmail.com';
        //public $FromName    = 'GMail Test';    
        public $WordWrap = 75;

        public function __construct($exceptions = null)
        {
           parent::__construct($exceptions);
           $this->isSMTP();
           $this->isHTML();
        }

        public function subject($subject)
        {
           return $this->Subject = $subject;
        }

        public function body($body)
        {
           return $this->Body = $body;
        }

        public function send()
        {
            $this->AltBody = $this->html2text($this->Body);
            return parent::send();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me example code for my use.So that i can understand.

Comment: One more thing i have commented the  $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
            $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);

Comment: And now email is coming properly But not using Phpmailer but with same mail() function

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/vol8_6/ultimatefreehost.in/ltm_18359698/htdocs/classes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1466

Answer (score 0):

which email you send 
ex: gmail or hotmail

if ssl not present 
hotmail automatically deletes email without even notifying. You have add exception for particular sender.